# Python json.dumps with string interpolation?

Tags: python, json

Let's say I want to create a json object following the structure:

```
{"favorite_food":["icecream","hamburguers"]}
```

to do so in python, if i know the whole string in advance, I can just do:

```
json.dumps({"favorite_food":["icecream","hamburguers"]})
```

which works fine.

my question though is, how would i do the same thing if i wanted to get the object as a result of a string interpolation? For example:

```
favorite food = 'pizza'
json.dumps({"favorite_food":[%s]}) %favorite_food
```

the issue i found is, if I do the interpolation prior to calling the `json.dumps`:

```
dict=  '{"favorite_food":[%s]}' % favorite_food
```

if i then do `json.dumps(dict)` , because of the string quotation, the json_dumps returns:

```
{"favorite_food":[pizza]}
```

that is, is not a dict anymore (but a string with the structure of a dict)

How can i solve this simple issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not just:

```
>>> food = "pizza"
>>> json.dumps({"favorite_food":[food]})
'{"favorite_food": ["pizza"]}'
```

`json,dumps` takes actual values as input --- that is, real dicts, lists, ints, and strings.  If you want to put your string value in the dict, just put it in.  You don't want to put in a string representation of it, you want to put in the actual value and let `json.dumps` make the string representation.

Comment: That's a good point -- and likely what OP actually wants (+1).  Of course, if `food` is a type that json can't handle, but has a reasonable string representation, this will fail.  Of course, you could then just do `[str(food)]` ... Problem solved.

Comment: yeah, this answer would help in the cases i have been trying. Thanks so much Sir.

Comment: @mgilson if the default encoder doesn't work--that is, op presents it with a type that cannot readily be translated into JSON (https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html?highlight=json#encoders-and-decoders) --then they can extend `JSONEncoder` and present the class in the `cls` keyword argument to `dumps()`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html?highlight=json

Comment: it will create problem in the case of boolean

Answer (score 1):

How about below:

```
favorite_food = 'pizza'
my_dict =  {"favorite_food":[favorite_food]}
print json.dumps(my_dict)
```

I found this is very simple.

Comment: @BrenBarn beat you by a couple minutes ;-).

Comment: Ya.. I just took time in posting :(